# Options for HTML 5 local database storage

Tags: html

I am using HTML 5. Wanted to know what kind of local database storage is available.
The localStorage (used key value pair) has a limiation on it so wanted to know if there is something else available.

Comment: tell me what kind of data store rather key value pair ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page has a list of varieties of storage methods that can be used with HTML5: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Here's a page explaining the differences between the different methods:
http://csimms.botonomy.com/2011/05/html5-storage-wars-localstorage-vs-indexeddb-vs-web-sql.html

If you're looking for more than just key-value storage, maybe you want WebSQL database. Though, I believe that's being deprecated.